# Why I cannot put where in SQL?

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to insert a sublevel to a table from form like in the picture but why can't I use where?

[image]

```
String sql = "insert into BE_Tracker(sub_item) values(?) where id="+id+" ";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(2,addsubItem);
```

Comment: `INSERT` syntax cannot have `WHERE` clause

Comment: Because that doesn't make sense. Maybe you meant `update`? Or you need to insert the `id` as well. It's hard to answer without knowing your table structure.

Comment: you can do this with update , since you have already inserted it.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use where in insert into query in this way.

You can use it like, something like that
insert into MyTable1 select id,name from MyTable2 where id >5

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really wanted an `UPDATE` here:

```java
String sql = "UPDATE BE_Tracker SET sub_item = ? WHERE id = ?";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1, addsubItem);
st.setString(2, id);
st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: im trying to add another row for the sub item. lets say i insert car first then i want to add another row of motorcycle under the same id

Comment: I have answered your original question.  If you have a follow up, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT (...) VALUES (...)` query cannot use with finding option `WHERE ... = ...`.

1. `Insert` row on table `BE_Tracker`.
2. Find rows in table `BE_Tracker` with `'WHERE'` option with `'SELECT', 'UPDATE'` or `'DELETE'`.